# Make an arbitrary Linux application use a specific IP address for outbound connections

Tags: linux, routing, local

Having multiple IP addresses, is it possible to make an arbitrary network application use only specific IP address when establishing connections to the outside world?

System-wide, routes can be used. Some applications are configurable for this. But is there a generic way?

Say, a browser should always use an IP bound to 'eth0', and a torrent-client should use an IP bound to 'eth1'.

*Technically*, this should explicitly pass a specific IP address to `bind(2)` call when a client socket is created.

Comment: An app that makes connections to the outside world is a client app. And bind() is specific to server sockets.

Comment: You,re wrong: bind() is ok for client sockets, but is not obligatory: it's used when when an application desires to use a specific IP address or port for outbound connections. I'm 100% sure it works so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of the LD_PRELOAD environment variable and "function interposition" to modify the behavior of your network programs.  See [this article](http://www.jayconrod.com/cgi/view_post.py?23) for an example, and Google [function interposition](http://www.google.com/search?q=function+interposition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) for more information.

You could, for example, override the "socket" system call so that every socket() call was followed by an appropriate bind() operation.

NB: This technique can be lots of fun to play with (for example, I once wrote something that would let me "open" URLs for editing with arbitrary text editors), but can be tricky to get right.

Comment: Wow, great! That's exactly what I wanted, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

My only suggestion would be to utilize iptables to redirect the traffic from one interface to another.

Here's a link to someone else who did something similar: http://straylink.wordpress.com/2006/08/16/using-iptables-to-redirect-packets/

Essentially, the command was this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 198.168.1.254 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

To completely steal the content (in case it disappears),

> The above rule adds a PREROUTING command to your nat table, stating any TCP packets 
>   destined for 192.168.1.254 on port 80 should be redirected to localhost port 8080. So 
>   breaking down the above example into template format, you have

```
 iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p PROTO -d DEST_IP --dport DEST_PORT -j REDIRECT --to-ports LOCAL_PORTS
```