# Have mysql command line use eth1 instead of eth0 to connect

Tags: mysql

When running a command like:

```
mysql -u mysql -h sql.remoteaddress.com
```

mysql is connecting using the eth0 interface.  How do I ask it to use the eth1 interface which has a different IP address than eth0.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll like my related question: http://serverfault.com/questions/93740/restrict-an-arbitrary-application-to-a-specific-ip-address-in-linux

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set a routing rule so that connections going to the network where sql.remoteaddress.com resides goes through eth1 rather than the default at eth0.

Try "route --help" to see the description of how to add a route.  You'll likely need root/admin access to set up the routing rule.